# php, mysql, arrays - how to get the row name

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative-array

I have the following code

```
while($row = $usafisRSP->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $Applicantid = $row['Applicantid'];
    $unique_num = $row['unique_num'];

    // .................

    $hidden_fields = array($Applicantid, $unique_num, $regs_t ....);
    $hidden_values = array();

   foreach ($hidden_fields as $key => $value) {
       $hidden_values[$value] = "$key = ".base64_decode($value)."<br>";
       echo $hidden_values[$value];
   }
}
```

and the result is something like this

```
0 = 116153840
1 = 136676636
2 = 2010-12-17T04:12:37.077
3 = XQ376
4 = MUKANTABANA
```

I would like to replace 0, 1, 2, 3 etc with some custom values like "Id", "application name" to make the result like

```
id = 116153840
application name = 136676636
etc ..
```

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `$hidden_fields = array(...` line with the following:

```
$hidden_keys = array('id', 'Applicantid', 'unique_num');
$hidden_fields = array_intersect_key($row, array_fill_keys($hidden_keys, NULL));
```

If you want to suppress all fields with value 0, either use

```
$hidden_fields = array_filter($hidden_fields, function($v) {return $v != 0;});
```

(this will completely omit the 0-entries) or

```
$hidden_fields = array_map($hidden_fields, function($v) {return ($v==0?'':$v);});
```

(this will leave them blank). If you're using an older version than 5.3, you'll have to replace the anonymous functions with calls to create_function.

Comment: thanks a lot for the response . Can you help me a little bit more . I would like to do not display the content of a specific key/value if the value=0 . I have the following code but it doesn't work ------
if(base64_decode($value) == 0)
{
$hidden_values[$value] = "";
}

Comment: @Michael updated to include this requirement. Feel free to ask another stackoverflow question for additional requirements, just make sure it does not start with "First, read my previous question: ..." ;)

Answer (score 0):

I assume not every field in your row should be a hidden field. Otherwise you could just do `$hidden_fields = $row`.

I would create an array that specifies the hidden fields:

```
$HIDDEN = array(
     'id' => 'Id', 
     'Applicantid' => 'application name', 
     'unique_num' => 'whatever'
);
```

And then in your `while` loop:

```
while(($row = $usafisRSP->fetch_assoc())){

    $hidden_fields = array();

    foreach$($HIDDEN as $field=>$name) {
        $hidden_fields[$name] = $row[$field];
    }

    //...

    foreach($hidden_fields as $name => $value) {
        $hidden_fields[$name] = $name . ' = ' . base64_decode($value);
        echo $hidden_values[$name];
        // or just echo $name, ' = ',$hidden_fields[$value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
   $hidden_values[$value] = "$key = ".base64_decode($value)."<br>";
   echo $hidden_values[$value];
}
```

This could give you something relevant. Through accessing the string keys from the row array which contains the string keys

Comment: This would set every field in `$row` as hidden field.